# How to deal with OP providing an answer in the question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580750/linux-ttyusb0-disconnect-and-reconnect-programmatically-resolved), and felt that I should remove ' - resolved' from the title; this isn't a forum.

However, the resolution is provided by the OP, and in the OP.

If I remove it, obviously the content should be preserved (it is a good answer - and possibly has two favourites) - but the only way for me to do that would lead to it being attributed to me.

As it stands, I have [edited the title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21580750/revisions), and [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580750/linux-ttyusb0-disconnect-and-reconnect-programmatically-resolved#comment39089786_21580750) that the answer should be provided as an answer.

What is the 'correct' way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Asking the questioner to post a solution as an answer is a good first approach.

But you can also do it yourself (for example if the questioner hasn't been active for a while). Then the answer should probably be community wiki and with attribution.